# Advance Select Query - FIFO

Tags: mysql, select, fifo

I have a table with columns id, item, qty and expiration date. I have to select item with a given total qty based on expiration date. The item that expires first need to be the priority to select. The query works fine if the item has different expiration date but, my problem is if the item has the same expiration date it does not return any row. Please check out the query below.

```
SELECT t.ID,
   t.itemcode,
   t.qty,
   t.expdate,
   t.total,
   t.prev_total,
   CASE WHEN t.total > 500 THEN 500 - t.prev_total ELSE t.qty END AS total
FROM
(
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.itemcode,
       t1.qty,
       t1.expdate,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.qty) FROM put_in t2
        WHERE t2.expdate <= t1.expdate AND t2.itemcode = 'ITEM01') AS total,
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(t2.qty) FROM put_in t2
        WHERE t2.expdate < t1.expdate AND t2.itemcode = 'ITEM01'), 0) AS prev_total
FROM put_in t1
WHERE t1.itemcode = 'ITEM01'
) t
WHERE t.total - t.qty < 500 AND
  t.itemcode = 'ITEM01'
ORDER BY t.expdate;
```